# Kafka consumer client creation singleton instance vs static method

Tags: java, design-patterns, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Please tell which one is the best practice to create Kafka consumer client.

```
public class KafkaConsumerFactory {

public static createKafKafkaConsumer(){
       KafkaConsumer consumer = new KafkaConsumer<   (getKafkaConsumerProperties());
      consumer.subscribe(Collections.Singleton.(getTopic()));
      return consumer;
}
```

Or

```
public class KafkaConsumerFactory {

private static KafkaConsumer consumer;  

@Synchronized
public static KafkaConsumer createKafKafkaConsumer(){

if(consumer = null)
    {
      consumer = new KafkaConsumer< (getKafkaConsumerProperties());
      consumer.subscribe(Collections.Singleton.(getTopic()));
    }

 return consumer;
}
}
```

Will there be any considerable benefit in having singleton Kafka consumer client in production environment ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kafka Consumer is not thread safe so it shouldn't be a Singleton. 
But in case of Producer, as it is thread safe and is recommended to have single instance.